# format and Print a list in a file

Tags: python, list, file

i have one list with some coordinates in it, when i am printing it like that:

```
for i in range(0,len(List)):
    print("".join(["(%d, %d) \n" % (y[i], y[i+1]) for y in (List)]))
```

the output is this:

```
(0, 3) 
(0, 2) 
(0, 1) 
(1, 1) 
(1, 2) 
(2, 2) 
(2, 1) 
(3, 1) 
(3, 0) 
(2, 0) 
(1, 0) 
(0, 0)
```

i want to save the output in a .txt, but that is not a problem, my problem is that the .txt must be formmated like this:

```
(0, 3), (0, 2)
(0, 2), (0, 1)
(0, 1),(1, 1)
(1, 1),(1, 2)
(1, 2),(2, 2)
.....
```

i've tried many things but nothing worked..
it must be easy, but i am new to python
thank you in advance

Comment: Looks like you want to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) and group into 4's, then format

Comment: Try not to do complex expressions like that because it isn't very pythonic - at least try to use comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
l = [(0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]

for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    print(', '.join([str(l[i]), str(l[i+1])]))

# (0, 3), (0, 2)
# (0, 1), (1, 1)
# (1, 2), (2, 2)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, but instead of (0, 3), (0, 2) i have [0, 3], [0, 2]

Comment: It means you get lists earlier in your code. You can turn the lists into tuples with `tuple([0, 3]) # returns (0, 3)`.

Comment: This doesn't work. The latter number remains the same.

Comment: when i print my list is like that [[0, 3], [0, 2],......], it's not like the above example  of viod.The viod answer is working but the output is with brackets not parenthesis, and i tried this thing with the tuple

Comment: @user2911293: this is because you have a list of lists, and not a list of tuples. To turn your whole list of lists into a list of tuples, you can use the following: `l = [tuple(x) for x in l]` where `l` is your list. Then you can use my answer above exactly as it is.

Comment: another minor problem, the code works and the output is correct, but i am getting this error:      `print(', '.join([str(L[i]), str(L[i+1])]), file=fo)`    
`IndexError: list index out of range` ,am i doing something wrong?

Comment: This is very probably because you have an odd number of elements in your list. You will have to handle the last element separately, for example by iterating only in `range(0, len(l)-1, 2)`, and then accessing the last element with `l[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
mylist = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
# That doesn't have to be the numbers though, you can use your own.

for a, b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]):
    print("{}, {}".format(a, b), file = myfile) # Will print to myfile.
```

That's assuming that you are printing to an open file. Leave the `file` argument out if you don't want to print anywhere else, but the default screen.

in `myfile.txt`:

```
(0, 0), (0, 1)
(0, 1), (0, 2)
(0, 2), (1, 0)
(1, 0), (1, 1)
(1, 1), (1, 2)
(1, 2), (2, 0)
(2, 0), (2, 1)
(2, 1), (2, 2)
```

The output is in tuples, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides other answers playing with indices, you can also use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a, b, c, d in zip(List, List[1:], List[2:], List[3:]):
    print('({}, {}), ({}, {})'.format(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding expected output:

```
l = [(0, 3), (0, 2), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]

for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]):
    print str(i) + "," + str(j) # or print ",".join([str(i),str(j)])

#output
(0, 3),(0, 2)
(0, 2),(0, 1)
(0, 1),(1, 1)
(1, 1),(1, 2)
(1, 2),(2, 2)
```

If you want list chunking with 2 elements,Try this

```
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]


for i,j in list(chunks(l,2)):
    print ",".join([str(i),str(j)])

#output
(0, 3),(0, 2)
(0, 1),(1, 1)
(1, 2),(2, 2)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code:

```
for i in range(0,len(List)):
    print("".join(["(%d, %d) \n" % (y[i], y[i+1]) for y in (List)]))
```

Turning this into a list comp.

```
t = ["".join(["(%d, %d) \n" % (y[i], y[i+1]) for y in (List)]) for i in range(0,len(List))]
```

(equivalent to)

```
s = []
for i in range(0,len(List)):
    s.append("".join(["(%d, %d) \n" % (y[i], y[i+1]) for y in (List)]))
```

Then:

```
first = True
other = None
r = ""
for i in t:
    if not first:
        r += other+", "+i+"\n"
        first = True
    else:
        other = i
        first = False
f = open("out.txt","w")
f.write(t)
f.close() #go to notepad
```

Comment: `/n` **isn't** a new line... you're attempting to write to a file that's not opened in *write* mode... as for the rest of it... needs some work :) (the output won't match what the OP wants, even if the logic is correct - did you test this at all?)

Comment: Bud, what happened to setting your reading options in `open` and your wrong newline tokens.